# Simulating key press in C++ for use in QML for virtual keyboard

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, virtual-keyboard

For my QML based application I would like to have a virtual keyboard (Qt Enterprise is such a tease, but 200$< is beyond my capabilities), so I decided to write my own. But I not quite sure how:

Here is how I see the code:

**keypress.h**

```
#ifndef KEYPRESS_H
#define KEYPRESS_H

#include <QObject>

class KeyPress : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit KeyPress(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE void virtKeyPress(const int& Char);

signals:
    void virtKeyPressed(const int& source);

private:
    int vKey;
};

#endif // KEYPRESS_H
```

**keypress.cpp**

```
#include "keypress.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>

KeyPress::KeyPress(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

}

void KeyPress::virtKeyPress(const int &Char){

    vKey = Char;
    QKeyEvent event(QEvent::KeyPress, vKey, Qt::NoModifier);
    // Here I guess I should do somthing like "sendEvent(parent, &event);" or whatever, but nothing seems to work.
    emit virtKeyPressed(vKey);


}
```

I have a few ideas on how to inplement this in just qml, but where’s the fun in that. :)
So I would like to ask for your guidance on the subject.
Btw, I’ve searched through info on the web, yet no working code found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending a key event to a Qt Quick object is like :

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent (engine->rootObjects().first(), event);
```

You can also take a look at [Input Panel Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-tools-inputpanel-example.html). It shows how to input text into widgets by  an input panel using  only the pointer and no keyboard.

Another one is [VirtualKeyboard](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/VirtualKeyboard?content=107388). See the source code and change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer but I'm aware of that method. The thing that I can't quite work out is how to send these events to QQmlApplicationEngine engine; declared in **main.cpp**.  My application is mostly Qt Quick based with elements of C++, so keyboard is required to work in QML envirement. Can You help me with that?

Comment: @DarkMalex You can keep a pointer to the `QQmlApplicationEngine` and send events to it's objects. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out soon, but it looks ok.

Comment: Sorry for noobness, but can you give me an example of a pointer to "engine" since my attempts to create one are futile (just like most attempts I found on the net). If you wish you can PM me.

Comment: You can have a pointer to the engine as a class member and assign it in main.pp when you create an instance of your class : `QQmlApplicationEngine engine("main.qml");` `MyVirtualKeyboard keyboard;` `keyboard.engine = &engine;`

Comment: you can also send it to `(QObject *)QGuiApplication::focusWindow()` which is a static method, so no need to save or pass around pointers